# Cant play games fullscreen

Tags: ati, screen, games, fullscreen

I have installed several games from steam, but when I open all of them they go fullscreen and the screen is black. I can here the sounds of the game but can see nothing. My gpu is a AMD Radeon 6858 and I have Catalyst 13.4 on Ubunt 12.10. Any ideas as to how I can go about preventing this?

Comment: Elementary OS seems not an official Ubuntu derivative...

Comment: What window manager are you using?

Comment: My window manager is Lightdm

Comment: @Shingaling - your original question stated you were using Elementary.  Why have you reinstalled using 12.10?  Since you have just reinstalled ... suggest you reinstall 12.04 or install 13.04.

Comment: I just changed back to Ubuntu out of prefrence. I guess I could try go back to the odler 12.04, but 13.04 for some reason refuses to boot. Thats a different topic though.  But I have the excact same issue with Ubuntu as I did in Elementary though.

Comment: 12.04 isn't older than 12.10, since it's the LTS release...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

> System Settings
>   Keyboard
>   Shortcuts
>   Windows

.......and set the Toggle full screen shortcut to ***f11*** then after launching the desired app in steam, press **f11** to enter full screen mode :)

Comment: Although that is a very useful, its not the problem I have. The games already, by default open in fullscreen mode, but I can't see anything, my monitor goes black. I can hear that the game is playing though.

Comment: Never mind this actually did help. Although the games already open in full screen mode, pushing f11 takes them out of full screen mode so now I'm actually able to use them, and more importantly adjust each game to the proper resolution of my monitor. SO! Now I can play games full screen. Thank you!!!

Comment: Okay. I guess that was a problem with the Steam games then